# Wso2 ESB - Payloadfactory with a few number of arguments

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I know how to use Payloadfactory mediator with listing all input arguments, but My backend service has many input arguments (120 input arguments). I want to use PayloadFactory Mediator to change only a few number of input arguments without listing other elements in payloadfactory arguments.

sample input xml for back-end service:

```
<p:echoStringArrays xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
     <!--0 or more occurrences-->
     <a>teststr1</a>
     <!--0 or more occurrences-->
     <b>teststr2</b>
     <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
      <c>1</c>
  </p:echoStringArrays>
```

My payloadfactory is ( to change 'a' element and pass other 119 elements automatically without listing them)

```
  <inSequence>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <p:echoStringArrays xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><!--0 or more occurrences--><a xmlns="">test</a>
           </p:echoStringArrays>
        </format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="http://desktop-iofs8c5:8280/services/echo"/>
  </endpoint>
```

When i call my proxy service, this error occurs:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Code>
    <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
 </soapenv:Code>
 <soapenv:Reason>
    <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">unknown</soapenv:Text>
 </soapenv:Reason>
 <soapenv:Detail/>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use enrich medaitor to change just some of elements

Comment: Can you write down an example? ( for this echo service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks simar!

I have used enrich mediator to modify the existing payload.

solution:

```
<property name="test" value="test" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <enrich>
        <source type="property" clone="true" property="test"/>
        <target xpath="//a"/>
     </enrich>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following sample should work for this requirement. If you need to create payload factories with different number of input parameters you need to do it selectively.

```
<payloadfactory>
      <format>
               <m:echoStringArrays xmlns:m="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
                  <m:a>teststr1</m:a>
                  <m:b>teststr2</m:b>
                  <m:c>teststr3</m:c>
               </m:echoStringArrays>
            </format>
</payloadfactory>
```